# How to declare variable to use like that variable["name1"] in C#

Tags: c#

I want to declare a variable like this in C#

```
public anyType variable;
```

and then I can use it like this

```
variable["name1"] = anyValue1;
variable["name2"] = anyValue2;
```

I cannot find out any solution to declare what type of variable is to use it that way.
Please help me.

I appreciate any comments

---

Additional information:
I have a class:

```
public class Template
{
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public string Content {get; set;}
}
```

I want to set value for Template Content and Template Name like this

```
Template t = new Template();
t["Name"] = "template1";
t["Content"] = "templatecontent1";
```

not:

```
Template t = new Template();
t.Name = "template1";
t.Content = "templatecontent1";
```

I mean like a table attribute. Here I have table Template, it has 2 columns Name and Content.  So that I can query Template["Name"] and Template["Content"]
Thanks

Comment: Can you say more about what the `anyValue` s are, or is it indeed going to be *any* value?

Comment: Also what is `anytype`? What types can it be? It can't be *any* type because some types don't support this.

Comment: @Mark I think that's what the question *is* : "what should `anyType` actually be?"

Comment: @AakashM: I read it as 'How can I do this with any type?' but the question is sufficiently vague that either interpretation might be right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type you need is `Dictionary<string, object>`. You can substitute `object` for whatever the type of `anyValue1` and `anyValue2` is.

EDIT: To allow indexers to set properties, you'll almost certainly need reflection. Try this setter on your `Template` class:

```
public string this[string field]
{
  get
  {
    PropertyInfo prop = GetType().GetProperty(field);
    return prop.GetValue(this, null);
  }
  set
  {
    PropertyInfo prop = GetType().GetProperty(field);
    prop.SetValue(this, value, null);
  }
}
```

There's no error handling in the above example though, so it'll fail horribly if you try setting a property that doesn't exist, or isn't a string, or doesn't have a getter/setter. You will need to add `using System.Reflection` to your uses clauses.

Comment: NB: If this is used with value types it will incur the un/boxing overhead. And to get your type back out a cast will be required.

Comment: Avoid the boxing/unboxing by replacing `object` as the value type with something more specific.

Comment: Well, I intended `object` to be an example, rather than a specific solution; I've made my answer clearer.

Comment: NP.. although to be honest, if I were in your position, I might re-think my design, this doesn't feel like the best way of working. Incidentally, I slightly corrected the example; I forgot to include the 'return' statement in the getter!

Answer (score 5):

You can see this tutorial on [indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465%28VS.71%29.aspx).

```
public Foo this[string index] 
{
    get { /* ... */ }
    set { /* ... */ }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for indexers: [link1](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/1547581/Using-Indexers-in-C.htm), [link2](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/04/c-indexers/), [link3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx)

```
    public class MyType
    {
        public string this[int index]
        {
            get 
            { 
                //getter implementation
            }
            set 
            { 
                //setter implementation
            }
        }
    }

    public class Usage
    {
        public MyType usageType = new MyType();

        public Usage()
        {
            usageType[0] = "xx";
        }
    }
```

If you need you can always define generic type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx, indexing with string: http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Language-Basics/IndexingwithanStringIndex.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection techniques but be seriously cautious.

```
public class Template
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(Template).GetProperty(name).GetValue(this, null).ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            typeof(Template).GetProperty(name).SetValue(this, value, null);
        }
    }
}
```